# how to find response code after httparty form POST

Tags: post, httparty, http-response-codes

I have made a POST to a site using Httparty with the following code:

```
HTTParty.post("http://example.com", :body => application_hash.to_json, :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

How can I check what the response code was for this submission?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The return value of the post method is a `HTTParty::Response` object, which has a code method. Assign your response to a variable and use that to take a look at the http status code:

```
response = HTTParty.post("http://example.com", :body => application_hash.to_json, :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
response.code
```

Comment: Thanks, along with print response.code at the end of the line I was able to output the response to the command line.